# Could not build Objective-C module 'ContactsUI'

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

(XCode 10, mac os 10.13.6)

I cloned a project and tried to run but XCode is giving this error :

> /Users/cac/Desktop/temp/contact_test/contact_test/ViewController.swift:10:8:
>   Could not build Objective-C module 'ContactsUI'

I created a simple application and tried to include ContactsUI, but it can't run again, this is my simple code :

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI
import Contacts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


}
```

but this is result :

[image]

Comment: Try to open your project with extension .xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate what I think your steps should have been by doing the following:

- created a single view Swift application
- selected my main project in the Project Navigator, then the "General" tab, then clicked on the "+" button under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", selected "Contacts" and "ContactsUI" and added both of them
- checked that they appeared in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries list
- replicated your exact code in the ViewController.swift file
- built the app

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to XCode 10.1 and now it's working ok!